# Spring configuration / properties different per request

Tags: spring

I need to figure out if the following scenario is possible in Spring.

If we have different services / databases per region, can Spring facilitate directing calls to those services / databases per request from a single deployment?  To give an example, all requests from user X will be directed to services / databases in the EAST region while all requests from user Y will be directed to services / databases in the WEST region.

Obviously connections to each database will use connection pooling, so the configuration will need to differ, not just properties.  When other services are initialized, there is authentication done, so it's not just about databases connections.

This being Spring, I'd like to avoid having to pass implementations around.  Can I direct Spring to use a specific configuration per request?  Is there a better way to accomplish this?

-- **Edit** --

Technically it can be done like this, though this isn't exactly easily maintainable.

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:region1.properties")
public class TestIndependentConfigurationRegion1Configuration {

    @Bean
    public String sampleServiceUrl(@Value("${sample.service.url}") String value) {
        return value;
    }

    @Bean
    public TestIndependentConfigurationSampleService testSampleService() {
        return new TestIndependentConfigurationSampleService();
    }

}
```

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:region2.properties")
public class TestIndependentConfigurationRegion2Configuration {

    @Bean
    public String sampleServiceUrl(@Value("${sample.service.url}") String value) {
        return value;
    }

    @Bean
    public TestIndependentConfigurationSampleService testSampleService() {
        return new TestIndependentConfigurationSampleService();
    }

}
```

```java
@Controller
public class TestIndependentConfigurationController {

    protected ApplicationContext testRegion1ApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestIndependentConfigurationRegion1Configuration.class);

    protected ApplicationContext testRegion2ApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestIndependentConfigurationRegion2Configuration.class);

    @RequestMapping("/sample/service")
    @ResponseBody
    public String testSampleService() {
        TestIndependentConfigurationSampleService testSampleService = null;
        if(/* region 1 */) {
            testSampleService = (TestIndependentConfigurationSampleService) testRegion1ApplicationContext.getBean("testSampleService");
        }
        if(/* region 2 */) {
            testSampleService = (TestIndependentConfigurationSampleService) testRegion2ApplicationContext.getBean("testSampleService");
        }
        testSampleService.executeSampleService();
        return "SUCCESS";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with properties. BUT, you should look at (netflix) ribbon client that is integrated with spring. Some of the ribbon's features allow you to load balance request's between regions. You could customize the ribbon client to do what you want.

Some readings here :
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-ribbon.html